# Make axios request with variable from the state in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

### Issue Presentation

I am in the learning phase and I'm trying to build a project with react and redux.
I have created my actions, reducers and components and so far was good getting data from my API.
Now I'm trying to call an axios request (that is present in an action), but with a variable in the URL, but the variable is in the state.
**Basically what I want to achieve is:**

```
componentDidMount() {
        //call action to load profile data
        let address = this.props.checkweb.address;
        this.props.loadProfile(address);
    }
```

The problem with the above code is that `address` is empty when the component is mounted, and becomes available after a short time. If I use `setTimeout`, it works, but I do not know if it's a good way to do this. 
**This code works**.

```
componentDidMount() {
        //wait 1 sec and call action to load profile data
        setTimeout(function() {
           let address = this.props.checkweb.address;
           this.props.loadProfile(address);
        }, 1000); 
    }
```

The above code works and it loads my data, but as I mentioned, I do not know if it's fine to do this and it can't create future problems ? Of course, I will do some `if/else` to check if the `address` have a value, but I wrote it like that for the sake of simplicity.

### I'll post the code of Component, Action and Reducer to get a better view over the function

The part of the Action where `loadProfile()` is created

```
export const loadProfile = (address) => (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({
      type: 'PROFILE_REQUEST',
      isLoading: true,
      error: null
});
   return axios.get('https://localhost:8088/api/weapons/'+address)
.then(response => {
  dispatch({
        type: 'PROFILE_SUCCESS',
        isLoading: false,
        data: response.data
  });
})
.catch(err => {
  dispatch({
        type: 'PROFILE_FAILED',
        isLoading: false,
        error: err
  });
  console.error("Failure: ", err);
});
}
```

Here we have the reducer for the `loadProfile()`

```
let profileApiState = {
data: {},
isLoading: false,
error:null
}

const profileApi = (state = profileApiState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'PROFILE_REQUEST':
    case 'PROFILE_FAILED':
    return { 
        ...state, 
        isLoading: action.status, 
        error: action.error 
    };
    case 'PROFILE_SUCCESS':
    return {
        ...state, 
        data: action.data, 
        isLoading: action.status,
        error: null 
    };
    default: return {
        ...state
    }

}
}

export default profileApi;
```

And here we have the Component where I'm doing the rendering

```
class Inventory extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        //call action to load weapons
         let address = this.props.checkweb.address;
        this.props.loadProfile(address);
    }

render() {
return (
        <div>
            Some profile data 
            {this.props.profile.data}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
        return {
            checkweb: state.checkWeb,
            profile: state.profileApi
        };
};

export default connect (mapStateToProps, actionCreators)(Inventory);
```

#### TL;DR

I want to call an axios request with a variable (from the state) in the `componentDidMount()`, but the variable is not loaded immediatly so I can't call the action because the variable is null.

Comment: Why is the variable not immediately available? Is it being loaded asynchronously?

Comment: Are you using Redux-Thunk, or similar, for handling the asynchronous actions?

Comment: @djfdev Yes, it is also loaded asynchronously in another component that is mounted always (header).

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Yes, I'm using Redux Thunk

Answer (score 1):

You can use `componentWillReceiveProps` to launch your request when you receive your address prop :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!this.props.checkweb && nextProps.checkweb) {
        this.props.loadProfile(nextProps.checkweb.address);
    }
}
```

Edit: if you're able to get `address` with an async function (promise) you can do this :

```
componentDidMount() {
    getAsyncAddress().then((address) => {
        this.props.loadProfile(address);
    }
}
```